# Is it necessary to repeat "qu'il" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaire, subordonnées, coordination

- Ça ne me gêne pas qu’il fasse ~~~ et qu'il dise ~~~
- Ça ne me gêne pas qu’il fasse ~~~ et dise ~~~

If the subject changes from "il" to "elle", for example, I can understand that I need to repeat "que". But even when the subject is the same, do I still need to repeat "que"?

Comment: Both are entirely acceptable to me. I do not see a difference except the fact you use less words, less ink, save time...

Answer (score 4):

Les deux sont possibles. Il n'y a pas de différence de sens ou d'emphase.

À l'oral, on dit en général « qu'il fasse … et qu'il dise … », sauf si « … » est très court (déterminant-nom-adjectif, au delà on répète presque toujours). On répète la conjonction et le pronom pour rendre la phrase plus facile à suivre. À l'écrit, répéter « qu'il » est légèrement moins soutenu.